# Edit files in Windows Explorer through C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file-io, filesystems

I am creating an application that enables a user to replace the logos of programs with different logos. There will be multiple ways a user can choose to do this, however one of them I would like to use is to replace the original logo with a new one. So basically:

- Rename old logo to "*OldLogo* (Backup)"
- Add a new item *NewLogo* to the location of the old item

And then to the reverse the process should the user choose to:

- Delete the added *NewLogo*
- Rename *OldLogo* to its original name

The code for the bullet points mentioned above or the theory behind it would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: Look into the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class, with the static methods: Move, Delete, Copy. (To rename, move to same place with different name)

Comment: We will not able to provide code. We will be able to help with any specific issues you have faced once you have tried something. Please read a good guide on posting questions at SO here : http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 0):

1) Open file dialog for seleting new logo file
2) Rename old logo
3) Copy selected file to old logo subfolder and change its name
 reverse
1) Delete current logo file
2) rename old logo file to right name

Most of the operations you will do with Dictionary and File classes from .NET.

Comment: Sorry. I'm very new to this, and haven't really worked with classes yet. Do you know of any tutorials??? Thanks you all so much. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this one [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As Yorye Nathan already mentioned, the File class allows a lot of what you are looking for:
[MSDN File Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx)

You can use Copy to backup and overwrite your logos as required.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far. I wasn't sure where to start and my searches online kept returning results related to editing files within your solution. I looked at the link. Sorry if I'm completely off but do I have to add a using System.IO.File, because after IO the only option that comes up is Compression. I'm sorry to be so stupid. This is all very new to me.